# Argument is URL or path

Tags: python, argv

What is the standard practice in `Python` when I have a command-line application taking one argument which is

URL to a web page

or

path to a HTML file somewhere on disk

(only one)

is sufficient the code?

```
if "http://" in sys.argv[1]:
  print "URL"
else:
  print "path to file"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what the program must do. If it just prints whether it got a URL, `sys.argv[1].startswith('http://')` might do. If you must actually use the URL for something useful, do

```
from urllib2 import urlopen

try:
    f = urlopen(sys.argv[1])
except ValueError:  # invalid URL
    f = open(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: The `open() ` throws exception as well.

Comment: Don't forget `except IndexError:` as the user might not specify an argument, which will throw an index error. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Griffin: I've considered that a separate problem for the purpose of this answer.

Comment: @rplnt: yes, and the OP might or might not want to check for `IOError`. I'm just showing how `urlopen` and `open` may be combined, not how to tackle the larger problem. This snippet is enough for writing a generic `open_url_or_file` function that simply re-raises what it gets from `open`.

Comment: @larsmans That may be, but from the looks of it the OP doesn't know how to use exception handlers. I don't see any reason not to include it since it won't work if an argument isn't specified.

Comment: @FredFoo's implementation is the most correct exception handling. Only handle the exceptions you know how to handle, otherwise let the caller handle exceptions. In this case, if there's a file open or read or permissions error, etc. Let the caller know rather than catching and hiding the exception

Comment: Note that if argument is url with 404 error, then the code slows down.

Answer (score 24):

```
import urlparse

def is_url(url):
    return urlparse.urlparse(url).scheme != ""
is_url(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: Python 3 version:
`import urllib
urllib.parse.urlparse(url).scheme != ""`

Comment: This returns true for Windows file paths like `c:\users\user\foo.txt`.

Comment: Better to check if `urlparse(uri).scheme in ('http', 'https',)` because of Windows uri or uri starts with `file://`.

Answer (score 1):

Larsmans might work, but it doesn't check whether the user actually specified an argument or not.

```
import urllib
import sys

try:
    arg = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    print "Usage: "+sys.argv[0]+" file/URL"
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    site = urllib.urlopen(arg)
except ValueError:
    file = open(arg)
```