# Efficiently Distinguish File Path from URI / URL

Tags: c#, url, path

I have a very simple file transfer application (C# .NET) that allows users to move files from one file location to another on the local filesystem or to move files to an SFTP location.

The file operations are defined by a simple XML file which identifies the source and destination of each copy activity and valid strings can be either local file paths `C:\SomePath\SomeFile.txt`, or by an SFTP URL `sftp://somesite.com/somepath/somefile.txt`.

The actual operations performed by the program differ greatly depending on the source and destination type. (Akin to how Windows explorer can take a path or URL).

My question is, apart from general string parsing or reg-ex matching, is there an efficient or built-in means to classify a given string as being a file path type (Drive letter, colon, backslash) and a URL (protocol, colon, double-slash, etc.)?

This question is similar to [Distinguish a filename from an URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687916/distinguish-a-filename-from-an-url), but I'm looking for a .NET solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (new Uri(someString).IsFile)
```

If the string is not a valid path or URI, you'll get an exception.

You can also check the `Uri.Scheme` property, which will return `file`, `http`, etc.

Comment: Ah, wasn't aware file path strings could be passed to the Uri class constructor. Also, surprised to find that `Uri.Scheme` does recognize sftp as a protocol, even though it is not listed in the table on the [msdn documentation site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.scheme.aspx).

Comment: Read more carefully.  "The Scheme property returns the scheme used to initialize the Uri instance. **This property does not indicate that the scheme used to initialize the Uri instance was recognized**.

The following table shows examples of _some possible values_ returned by the Scheme property." (emphasis added)

Comment: Also, try `new Uri("abc:def")`

Comment: Ah, the devil is in the details. I think I am like many programmers out there who tend to skim documentation for tables, pictures, and sample code. Very good info.